# How can a function nested in an object knows its path?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I want to be able to call `fo` and generate a string from within (the callee) that represents its "object address" or path e.g. "example.fee.set.fo".

Would this require a function that iterates over the "root" object (i.e `example`)?

The purpose is to reference who’s calling to the server side.

```js
let example={
    fee:{
        set:{
            fo(){
                myName=????? //Here: generate a string with the value "example.fee.set.fo"
                $.ajax({data:{WhosCalling:myName,foo:'bar'}});
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `fo` only return its address or is it supposed to do some other things first? In which case could `fo` be decorated such as it receives its address as its first parameter?

Comment: @customcommander I missed this comment last night.  Yes, it could do lots of stuff.  I just want the address, so that I can pass it to the server side for context.  "who's calling?".  I don't see how I can achieve this with the variables in 'fo' and the address in the decoration.

Comment: This question smells like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's nice that you've provided some context, but can you explain why the server side cares about what variable names in an object were called? Likely, this is a poor solution to whatever problem X you're really trying to solve, and elaborating on that can likely allow us to provide a much better solution to it.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it!**

```js
let example={
  fee:{
    set:{
      fo(){ let myName = arguments.callee.address;
        console.log(myName);  //I'm now able to get the location name of this function
        //I can now use this to give context & identify myself to the server
        //IE $.ajax({data:{WhosCalling:myName,foo:'bar'}});
      },
}}};

function fn_addresses(obj,loc){
    $.each(obj,function(k,v){ let _loc=(loc?loc+'.':'')+k; //#.each requires jQuery -- pure js: for(var i in this)
        if(typeof v=='object'){ return fn_addresses(v,_loc) } //iterate through objects
        //↓ Below binds the address (ie 'example.fee.set.fo') to the functions namespace ↓
        if(typeof v=='function'){ v.address=_loc; }
    });
}

fn_addresses(example,'example'); //traverse the object adding 'address' to nested functions

example.fee.set.fo();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works and why this is a good solution to the problem? This doesn't offer future readers much information at all. I also recommend separating your operators with spaces, `loc += i;` and adding line breaks after each `;` because the code itself is pretty unreadable.

Comment: FYI - it is not recommended to use `arguments.callee`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: @ggorlen Read the solution and run the snippet.  Basically, the server side has no idea of context of what's calling the ajax and this is a way of giving it that via the calling functions address.

Comment: @intellilogic: Note that ggorlen is a well-respected members of the community who is trying to help.  There are plenty of reasons not to like this answer.  Imagine, for instance, adding `var somethingElse = {fi: {set: {fum: example.fee.set.fo}}}`.  Now when you call `somethingElse.fi.set.fum()`, you get back an address entirely different from how you called it.  The problem is that that functions are never merely object methods.  They are first class values can be used in many contexts.  The only realistic way to capture this information is the external technique from customcommander.

Comment: @intellilogic: The reason for the initial request for explanation is because code-only answers get little respect here.  A good answer will often use code, but without accompanying explanation does not much help others who come across it.  So answers are expected to have explanatory text and whatever code helps to illustrate that explanation.

Comment: @ScottSauyet good feedback, comments added. An option would be to ```fn_addresses(somethingElse,'somethingElse')``` however, yes, that would have to be executed in the correct order, so it's not ideal.  Implimentation of customcommander's solution would require rewriting all the code to pass of the functions execution to o_spy to exec/return; it's excessive and doesn't meet the requirements of the original question; simply getting that value inside of the existing function.  It also would have been more clear if he used my example instead of creating a separate one, even if he had to expand it

Comment: @intellilogic: Code comments help, but ideally there would be plain explanatory text.  What people were trying to point out is that your basic request is not something really supported by the language.  So any technique that approaches it will be something of a hack.  The cleanest one I can see is customcommander's decorators, and there are many variants of it, but I doubt anything will be really satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

Build a function that takes an object and the "root address" and recursively goes inside it, collecting the path to each nested function along the way.

Then wrap each of these nested functions with a function that accepts their arguments, apply them and return its address.

My recommendation would be that you keep your nested functions intact. But wrap them in a function that both executes them and talk to your server.

Example:

```js
const communicate = (path, fn) =>
  (...args) => {
    const addr = path.join('.');
    const exec = fn(...args);
    console.log(`Call from ${addr}: ${exec}`); // or $.ajax()
    return exec;
  };

const baz = x => x + 10;

const baz_with_communicate = communicate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], baz);

baz_with_communicate(10);
//=>LOG: "Call from foo.bar.baz: 20"
//=> 20
```

So now you just don't do the *"function with communicate"* business, this is done for you automatically in the `spy` function.

Judging by your comments you seem to be struggling with the concept of functions taking functions as parameters and returning other functions. It is however a powerful concept that you should get familiar with as it would help you design powerful abstractions.

---

*⚠️ This won't run on Edge (uses `Object.fromEntries` which is not supported yet)*

```js
const communicate = (path, fn) =>
  (...args) => {
    const addr = path.join('.');
    const exec = fn(...args);
    console.log(`Call from ${addr}: ${exec}`); // or $.ajax()
    return exec;
  };

const spy = (o, ...path) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .entries(o)
      .map(([k, v]) =>
        v !== null && typeof v === 'object'
          ? [ k
            , spy(v, ...path.concat(k))
            ]
          : typeof v === 'function'
            ? [ k
              , communicate(path.concat(k), v)
              ]
            : [ k
              , v
              ]));

const o_spy = spy(o, 'example');

console.log(o_spy.foo.bar.baz(5));
console.log(o_spy.bar.baz.bat(5));
```

```html
<script>
const o =
  { foo:
    { bar:
      { baz: x => x + 10 }}
  , bar:
    { baz:
      { bat: x => x + 20 }}};
</script>
```

Comment: How would that work inside of 'fo'?  It would have to be used on the caller, not the callee.  I want 'fo' to be able to "tell" the server side "his full name".

Comment: @intellilogic This is what I asked in your original question. Either you modify `fo` signature so that it can accept its address as its first parameter. Or you let the decorated function deals with the communication to the server. That way you keep things separated and clean: `fo` does it own thing and the decorator executes `foo` and communicate the address to your server.

Comment: I don’t understand how I’d get this back inside of the function.

fo(){ myName=????? /*"example.fee.set.fo"*/
 $.ajax({data:{WhosCalling:myName,foo:'bar'}}); }

Comment: @intellilogic You don't. You would (at least I would suggest you do so) typically add this kind of logic in the decorator. See `decorate` function. Currently I'm using `console.log` but it could do whatever you want. The key thing is that the decorator does the communication _and_ execute the decorated function for you.

Comment: This is all client side, I don't understand how I get that string value into the request; passing it to the server.  'foo' would have the values of 'fo'?  Can you write my actual example so I can understand.

Comment: Is it supposed to be spy('o',example)? [error pic](https://ibb.co/WWXQsd7)

Comment: @intellilogic I have updated the code and hopefully this is clearer now. The error you had is because you should have replaced `o` with your object `example`. The code is working but obviously I can't assist you into transposing an example into your own codebase.

Comment: Ok, that worked, this is awesome, thanks.  How do I get 'exec' into communicate, similar to the old example.

Comment: @intellilogic Really?! ;) This is exactly what I was trying to explain to you but somehow you just didn't acknowledge it. My recommendation is that you leave the two "processes" separated. Your nested functions should not try to communicate to your server. They do their own things. Then you decorate them with a function that receives a function address, communicate it to your server _and_ execute the function it decorates. If you want to see how that's done please see my edits. I'm not sure what else I can do now. Good luck.